# EaselJS Picture scaling blurred out

Tags: javascript, web, easeljs

Importing a picture to EaselJS with Bitmap:

```
var stage;
$(document).ready(function(){


    var gameCanvas = document.getElementById("game");
    stage = new createjs.Stage(gameCanvas);

    loadPics();





    function loadPics() {
        let image = new Image();
        image.src = "assets/img/island1.png";
        image.onload = loadPic;

    }

    function loadPic(event) {
        let bitmap = new createjs.Bitmap(event.target);
        bitmap.scaleX = 1;
        bitmap.scaleY = 1;

        bitmap.image.width = gameCanvas.width;
        stage.addChild(bitmap);
        stage.update();
    }

});
```

It doesn't matter if I export the picture from photoshop with 400x400 or 200x200

The picture is still all over the canvas.

If i scale it down

```
bitmap.scaleX = 0.2;
bitmap.scaleY = 0.2;
```

It becomes extremely blurred

Anyone knows a fix?

Comment: Maybe you're using CSS on the canvas? Make sure you're not adjusting canvas size in CSS but directly on the canvas element via either HTML or JS, otherwise aspect or pixel ratios can get weird

Comment: Using css to size it to Full Screen with 100%.Any way to do it without getting pixelated? @ppajer

Comment: Since you're using jQuery a simple `$('#game').width($(window).width()+'px')` should do the trick, same with height. If that works I'll delete this comment and turn it into an answer

Comment: Worked! Big Thanks. @ppajer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Canvas output can get pixelated if scaled with CSS

Make sure you're not adjusting canvas size in CSS but directly on the canvas element via either HTML or JS, otherwise canvas output can get distorted.

```
var stage;
$(document).ready(function(){


    var gameCanvas = document.getElementById("game"),
        windowWidth = $(window).width(),
        windowHeight = $(window).height();

    $(gameCanvas).width(windowWidth+'px');
    $(gameCanvas).height(windowHeight+'px');

    stage = new createjs.Stage(gameCanvas);

    loadPics();





    function loadPics() {
        let image = new Image();
        image.src = "assets/img/island1.png";
        image.onload = loadPic;

    }

    function loadPic(event) {
        let bitmap = new createjs.Bitmap(event.target);
        bitmap.scaleX = 1;
        bitmap.scaleY = 1;

        bitmap.image.width = gameCanvas.width;
        stage.addChild(bitmap);
        stage.update();
    }

});
```